# Segmentation fault passing an address specifically defined as a string

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, pass-by-reference, memory-address

Here's more code I whipped up since i was having trouble with my major program that I now fixed.

I have a function which modifies a series of bytes. In this example, the function is supposed to fill up the first 9 bytes of the char array with the numbers 1 through 9 consecutively.

Two tests are run. The first one is calling the function where the parameter is `(char*)&myvar`. The second test only uses `myvar` as a parameter. I thought I always had to use an & in front of a char array pointer when I want the string returned in the parameter portion of the function.

Why does this program only work when I don't prepend `(char*)&` to my char array variable?

When I do apply it, I receive a segmentation fault.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

int func(char* abc){
    char *p=abc;
    int n;
    for (n=1;n<10;n++){
    *p=(unsigned char)(n+48);p++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    char vars[1000]="234";
    char *myvar=vars;

    printf("Function test\n");
    int result=func((char*)&myvar); //causes segfault
    printf("Function result %s\n",myvar); //segfault here

    printf("Function test again\n");
    int result2=func(myvar);        //works
    printf("Function result %s\n",myvar);

    printf("DONE\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the cast to `(char *)`

Comment: Removing the cast will do nothing except cause compiler warnings. It does not in any way address the issue.

Comment: Take your code apart and find where exactly the seg fault is coming from.

Comment: @AlanAu Those warnings are precisely *why* you need to remove the cast. Telling the compiler to be quiet doesn't solve the problem it was complaining about. The warnings make the reason for the segfault obvious.

Comment: @mlp of course the cast should be removed. That's not the point. Just saying "remove the cast" does not really help the OP who clearly needs pointers explained. And that's why the answer provided below is good because it explains what needs to be done and why it needs to be done.

Answer (score 6):

> Why does this program only work when I don't prepend `(char*)&` to my char array variable?

Because doing that is completely wrong and not a thing that makes sense.

> I thought I always had to use an & in front of a char array pointer when I want the string returned in the parameter portion of the function.

You don't. (Also, you do not have a "char array pointer", and "when I want the string returned in the parameter portion of the function" doesn't make sense.)

When you need to pass a `char *` to a function that takes a `char *`, you do not need to put any special prefix in front of the pointer. You just pass it directly, the way you did with

```
int result2=func(myvar);
```

You could also have passed in `vars`, due to the automatic conversion from an array to a pointer to its first element, just like you were able to do `char *myvar=vars;` without any special casting.